# How to add import path prefix in nodejs?

Tags: node.js, typescript

I have noticed my Vue3 based project is configured to use `@` as a path prefix for imports, such as `import X from '@/pages/MyPage.vue'`, as opposed to `import X from '../pages/MyPage.vue'`, for example.

I am trying to see how we could apply the same approach to our node.js based projects, that are built using `tsc` and run using `ts-node`, in dev. Can anyone suggest how to go about this?

I did try add the following to the `compilerOptions` in `tsconfig.json`, but no impact:

```json
"paths": {
  "*": [
    "node_modules/*",
    "src/types/*"
  ],
  "@/": [
    "src/"
  ]
},
```

also:

```json
"paths": {
  "*": [
    "node_modules/*",
    "src/types/*"
  ],
  "@/*": [
    "src/*"
  ]
},
```

Error in code, in both cases, for `tsc --skipLibCheck` and in VS Code, is:

> Cannot find module '@/services/MyService' or its corresponding type declarations.

Ideally, any solution should work with VS Code as well.

Environment:

- typescript 3.9.5
- ts-node 8.10.2
- node 16.13.0

Comment: Have you tried wild card at the end of path specs? i.e. `"@/*"` and `"src/*`

Comment: I have now, but still gives: `Cannot find module '@/services/MyService' or its corresponding type declarations.`

Comment: Is it the same error or a different one? If it's a different error, then the original problem resolved and a new one occured. "still gives" confuses me.

Comment: This produces the same error. Have updated question.

Comment: you're specifying `src/*` but not `src/services`. Now you would do `src/**/*`, but it is [suggested](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/45024) that it's not recursively parsed, meaning you have to specify each sub dirs like `src/services/*`, `src/otherSubDir/*` etc